# an Equivalent condition for nilpotency of a finite group like of finite solvable group

Tags: solvable-groups, nilpotent-groups

We know that these two conditions are equivalent for finite groups :

i)  $G$ is solvable.

ii) If $\left|G\right|=mn\;$ and $(m,n)=1$ then G has a subgroup of order $m$.

Now are the following two conditions equivalent for finite groups? We know that i)$ \implies$ ii) holds.

i) $G$ is nilpotent.

ii) If $m$ divides $|G|$ then $G$ has a subgroup of order $m$

Comment: I voted not to close your Question, however it seems from the timing of things that you were able to find a counterexample rather quickly after posting.  Checking some small examples should be part of your research before posting.

Answer (score 1):

The collection of all finite groups $G$ for which there exists a subgroup of order $n$ for all $n\mid |G|$ are called CLT-groups (converse to Lagrange's theorem). Such groups lie strictly between the collection of supersoluble and soluble groups.

The correct equivalent condition for $G$ being nilpotent is that $G$ possesses a *normal* subgroup of each order dividing $|G|$. To prove this, $p$-groupshave normal subgroup of each order, and now use the fact that a nilpotent group is a product of its Sylow subgroups. This proves one direction. The other is that if a group has a normal subgroup of each order, then its Sylow subgroups are normal, and thus $G$ is nilpotent.

Answer (score 0):

I find a counterexample. $S_3$ has subgroups of order 1,2,3 and 6 but isn't direct product of it's sylow p-subgroups and hence isn't nilpotent.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).